# How can I get all Facebook public events based on location using Facebook Graph Api?

Tags: android, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-events

I want to get those Fields :
`Event(String id, String name, StringBuilder description, Integer attending, Image cover_photo, String start_time, String end_time, TimeZone timezone, Place place);`

- String id
- String name
- StringBuilder description
- Integer attending
- Image cover_photo
- String start_time
- String end_time
- TimeZone timezone
- Place place

Answer (score 0):

Before 4/4/2018 you could use the /search endpoint for that purpose but its no longer possible.

Please read: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

Comment: is there an other way to do it ?? i really need it for my project ! thanks .